# Angular 4 - TypeError: _co.send is not a function. (In '_co.send($event)', '_co.send' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, websocket

I am trying to create real-time chat between Django backend and Angular 4 frontend using PostgreSQL database. I would like to input my own text on frontend, press enter and send it. I get an error in Angular 4 - `TypeError: _co.send is not a function. (In '_co.send($event)', '_co.send' is undefined)`. I am not sure where is a problem. Any ideas what is wrong?

app.component.html:

```
<button (click)="sendMsg()">Send Message</button>

<h4>Type away! Press [enter] when done.</h4>
<div><key-up3 (keyup7)="send($event)"></key-up3></div>

<h4>Little Tour of Heroes</h4>
<p><i>Add a new hero</i></p>
<div><little-tour></little-tour></div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WebsocketService } from './websocket.service';
import { ChatService } from './chat.service';
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ WebsocketService, ChatService ]
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {
        chatService.messages.subscribe(msg => {
      console.log("Response from websocket: " + msg.message);
        });
    }

    private message = {
        message: 'this is a test message'
    }

  sendMsg() {
        console.log('new message from client to websocket: ', this.message);
        this.chatService.messages.next(this.message);
        this.message.message = 'this is a test message2';
    }



}

@Component({
  selector: 'key-up3',
  template: `
    <input #box (keyup.enter)="keyup7.emit(box.value)">
    <p>{{value}}</p>
  `
})
export class KeyUpComponent_v3 {
   @Output() keyup7 = new EventEmitter<string>();
}
```

websocket.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService {
  constructor() { }

  private subject: Rx.Subject<MessageEvent>;

  public connect(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
    if (!this.subject) {
      this.subject = this.create(url);
      console.log("Successfully connected: " + url);
    }
    return this.subject;
  }

  private create(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
    let ws = new WebSocket(url);

    let observable = Rx.Observable.create(
    (obs: Rx.Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
        ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
        ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
        ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
        return ws.close.bind(ws);
    })
let observer = {
        next: (data: Object) => {
            if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        }
    }
    return Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable);
  }

}
```

chat.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { WebsocketService } from './websocket.service';

const CHAT_URL = 'ws://localhost:8000/';

export interface Message {
    message: string
}

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
    public messages: Subject<Message>;

    constructor(wsService: WebsocketService) {
        this.messages = <Subject<Message>>wsService
            .connect(CHAT_URL)
            .map((response: MessageEvent): Message => {
                let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
                return {
                    message: data.message
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `sendMsg` function but missing the `send` function in your component?

Comment: There is `sendMsg()` in `app.component.ts:`. I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: But you are calling `(keyup7)="send($event)"` also, which is undefined.

Comment: Also check https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction, if you haven't yet.